# Separable verb zuhören

Tags: verb, separable

Why did the separable verb " zuhören " not separate here?

Obwohl ich gut zuhörte, verstand ich es nicht.

Is it also correct to say the following?

Obwohl ich hörte gut zu, verstand ich es nicht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obwohl ich gut zuhörte, …

That's a dependent clause. You can tell that both from the subordinating conjunction *obwohl* in front and from the missing verb in second position.

> … , verstand ich es nicht.

That's the main clause. It has a verb in second position. (First position is the dependent clause.)

> Is it also correct to say the following?

> <strike>Obwohl ich hörte gut zu, verstand ich es nicht.</strike>

No. That's wrong because *obwohl* cannot lead a main clause, and *ich hörte gut zu* is a main clause as it has a verb in second position.

In German, the position of the conjugated verb tells the type of clause. Much more reliably than conjunctions do. However, if there is a conjunction, it has to match the type of clause it is used in.

---

In general, separable verbs are **only** separated if they are the conjugated verb of a main clause. Compare:

> Du weißt, dass ich gut **zuhöre.**

> Ich **höre** gut **zu.**

So in the main clause, the conjugated stem is broken off and moved to second position. The prefix sticks to the end.

Let's add a modal:

> Du weißt, dass ich gut **zuhören kann.**

> Ich **kann** gut **zuhören.**

Here, the modal is the conjugated verb. So in the main clause, it's the modal that is moved to second position. The infinitive *zuhören* remains untouched.

And for the Partizip II, the -ge- is inserted between the seperable prefix and the stem:

> Du weißt, dass ich gut **zugehört habe.**

> Ich **habe** gut **zugehört.**

(There's a similar rule for the Gerundivum but I skip it for now.)

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihre Erklärung!

Answer (score 2):

Subjunction "obwohl" tells you that the verb needs to be in "last" position - seen many times with dependent clauses. When the verb is in "last" position, it is not separated.

Comment: Note that with a coordinating conjunction the 'zu' is separated: "Ich hörte gut zu, aber ich verstand es nicht."

Comment: @RDBury Your comment may be confusing, as it is phrased as if the conjunction has direct influence over it, but you just used it in addition to the verb-second clause